# Access third-party JAR file in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We uploaded two third-party JAR files to the Artifacts section in Azure DevOps, however when executing one of the JAR files (com.thr.jdbc:terajdbc4) we continue to get the below error. I have verified that the "Allow project scope build" is enabled in permissions and the "Limit job authorization scope to current project" is unchecked in Project setting.

All required permissions seems to be correct as well. Any help and direction is very much appreciated.

**Error Information (changed the Org name and GUID):**
*Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:Donotsolicit-teradata-sfdc:mule-application:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.thr.jdbc:terajdbc4:jar:0.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.thr.jdbc:terajdbc4:jar:0.2: Could not transfer artifact com.thr.jdbc:terajdbc4:Pom:0.2 from/to MuleSoft (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/{GUID}/_packaging/MuleSoft/maven/v1): The requested operation is not allowed. (403)*

**One additional point of note is that the other JAR file in the same Artifact location seems to be accessible as expected:**
*Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector from ClassRealm[extension>org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e] with priority 0.0 for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{GUID}/_packaging/_packaging/MuleSoft/maven/v1 with username=azureArtifactsAccessToken, password=****

Comment: On the assumption that this is a package coming from an upstream, be sure the build identity has Collaborator or higher permissions, not just Reader. Identities with only Reader permissions can't ingest new files from upstream.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. The build identity actually has Contributor access. One of the reasons why I cant figure out where the issue is with the not allowed error.

Comment: What's the result if you consume the package locally, can it access the packages?